# Wordpress - Disable jQuery scripts on certain post types

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to deregister some scripts on wordpress, but only for certain post types. I'm still quite new to wordpress and php so I'm struggling to figure out how this is done.
Here's my registered & enqueued scripts:

```
function test_script_method() {
    wp_register_script( 'jq', '/wp-content/themes/test/js/script.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jq' );
    wp_register_script( 'slideshow', '/wp-content/themes/test/js/slideshow.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slideshow' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_script_method');
```

So I split my jQuery into two files, as I don't need some of them on certain pages / post types.
First of all I'm trying to disable the `'jq'` script for all posts with the post type `'news'` and also on the `'archive-news.php'` and on a page titled `'home'` as well.
Is this at all possible?

Comment: possible duplicate question, see here:

[http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/loading-external-scripts-in-admin-but-only-for-a-specific-post-type][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/loading-external-scripts-in-admin-but-only-for-a-specific-post-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
enterfunction test_script_method() {
   global $wp_query;
   if ( "news" != get_post_type() && !(is_page('home')) ) {
    wp_register_script( 'jq', '/wp-content/themes/test/js/script.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jq' );
    wp_register_script( 'slideshow', '/wp-content/themes/test/js/slideshow.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slideshow' );
   }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_script_method'); code here
```

Comment: genius, this is perfect, thank you!! One more small question, how would I disable a script on 'archive-news', an archive page of all the news posts? Or would that be disabled on there too as they are classed as news post types?

Comment: Is a page template? Just add a third condition: && is_page("archive-news")